# TextView is Not Showing any Text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I just Installed Android Studio and Created a Project in it but whenever i add a TextView in it is not showing anything Even the `TextView` Already Created by the Android Studio Is not Showing 
`Activity.xml` code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="67dp"
        tools:text="Hello World" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        tools:text="sdfsfsfsfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        tools:text="Hello World" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any Help Would Be appreciated.

Comment: `TextView` is not constraint and your root is `ConstraintLayout`. Read about `ConstraintLayout` .

Answer (score 8):

Probably a late answer, but as long as it helps someone.

You are using the property `tools:text` for your last textview. The tools namespace is just for layout preview in android studio.

For the textview to display something in runtime, you must use the android namespace and `android:text` property like so:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World" />
```

Also, only the first textview is constrained. Try adding constraints to the remaining TVs.

And, in case your design window is not showing any text but a blank screen, you may have to change the Theme for Preview in the design window to match your app theme (Eg: Material theme, Light, AppTheme, etc.)
[The sixth button, which shows "Material Theme" right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWcEu.png)

Answer (score 5):

Try that for your constraint layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Hello World" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        tools:text="sdfsfsfsfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Hello World"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also, `id/textview` will not render anything when the app is run because there is no `android:text` property. `tools:text` is just for the layout editor.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        tools:text="Hello World" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using ConstraintLayout and it needs special properties to be provided to see all views. since you are a beginner as you say I recommend to start with linear layouts. replace your code with this one.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        tools:text="sdfsfsfsfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        tools:text="Hello World" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i tried but it is not showing any TextView Except blank screen

Comment: @fiverrfreelancer try to run it sometime the design is not built correctly but when you run it it fixed

Answer (score 0):

you need to constraint your widgets if you gonna use constraint layout.
First try with a linearlayout, it will be more simple if you just want to display a textview with a hello world

```
    <LinearLayout


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#134A80">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i tried but it is not showing any TextView Except blank screen

Comment: so you might have a problem with your android ide installation, because that linearlayout background isnt white

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:alignParentBottom="true"
        tools:text="Hello World" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        tools:text="sdfsfsfsfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Hello World" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i tried but it is not showing any TextView Except blank screen.

Comment: Right, this is exactly what not to do. Do not use the tools namespace. You will need to use the android namespace. Easy to gloss over if not paying attention.

Answer (score -2):

user android:text="hello world!"
instead of tool:text="hello world"

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers. *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*